# Why does webpack css loader add so many code to my bundle?

Tags: webpack, es6-module-loader, css-loader, sass-loader, commonschunkplugin

I have a typescript file called **DropdownMenu.ts** which looks like this

```
import DropdownMenuItem from './DropdownMenuItem';
import { createElem } from '../timeline/utils';
import { Dispatcher } from '../timeline/utils';
import { transition } from 'd3-transition';
// import './dropdown-menu.scss';

export default class DropdownMenu {
    // code omitted
}
```

I am using `sass-loader` and `css-loader` to process the sass file and output a separate css file for it. If I comment out the import statement for the sass style sheet, webpack's CommonsChunkPlugin generates the bundle with the correct amount of code. But if I remove the comment on the import statement for the stylesheet, then look inside the generated bundle file called **DropdownMenu.js** for this typescript module, webpack has added a huge amount of code for the css loader to work. Is there a way to remove these code or is it possible?

Comment: let me know if you find any solution.